# How to Apply number_format(); to different variables?

Tags: php, function, variables, number-formatting

I'm trying to output the prices for each items and their respective quantity. But I also want to know if there will be a function that I can use in order to use the ***number_format();***  *just once*. For example, **$beerQty** is just one of the variables that will hold the calculated price but I need to echo the value along with the number_format function without declaring it inside my HTML. Thanks in advance! :)

**Here is my PHP Code:**

```
<?php
// CURRENCY
$c          = '$';
// GET ALL INPUTS FROM CUSTOMER
# ChickBurger
$cbS        = $_POST['cbS'];
$cbL        = $_POST['cbL'];
# Fillet Burger
$fbS        = $_POST['fbS'];
$fbL        = $_POST['fbL'];
# Bacon Cheese Burger
$bcR        = $_POST['bcR'];
# French Fries
$ffS        = $_POST['ffS'];
$ffL        = $_POST['ffL'];
# Drinks
$colaQty    = $_POST['colaQty'];
$juiceQty   = $_POST['juiceQty'];
$beerQty    = $_POST['beerQty'];

// PRICES
# ChickBurger
define('CBS',2.75);
define('CBL',3.55);
$cbSQty     = 0.00;
$cbSQty     = $cbS * CBS;
$cbLQty     = 0.00;
$cbLQty     = $cbL * CBL;
# Fillet Burger
define('FBS',2.55);
define('FBL',3.55);
$fbSQty     = 0.00;
$fbSQty     = $fbS * FBS;
$fbLQty     = 0.00;
$fbLQty     = $fbL * FBL;
# Bacon Cheese Burger
define('BCR',4.25);
$bcQty      = 0.00;
$bcQty      = $bcR * BCR;
# French Fries
define('FFS',0.99);
define('FFL',1.99);
$ffSQty     = 0.00;
$ffSQty     = $ffS * FFS;
$ffLQty     = 0.00;
$ffLQty     = $ffL * FFL;
# Drinks
define('COLA',2.75);
define('JUICE',3.55);
define('BEER',4.25);
$cola       = 0.00;
$cola       = $colaQty * COLA;
$juice      = 0.00;
$juice      = $juiceQty * JUICE;
$beer       = 0.00;
$beer       = $beerQty * BEER; 
?>
```

**Here's the HTML**

```
<table width="600" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
    <tr align="center">
        <td>Items</td>
        <td>Size</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
    <tr height="30" align="center">
        <td width="200" rowspan="2">ChickBurger</td>
        <td width="200">Small / $2.75</td>
        <td width="200"><?php echo $c . number_format("$cbSQty",2,".",",") . ' / ' . $cbS; ?></td>
    <tr align="center">
        <td>Large / $3.55</td>
        <td width="200"><?php echo $c . number_format("$cbLQty",2,".",",") . ' / ' . $cbL; ?></td>
    <tr height="30" align="center">
        <td width="200" rowspan="2">Fillet Burger</td>
        <td width="200">Small / $2.25</td>
        <td width="200"><?php echo $c . number_format("$fbSQty",2,".",",") . ' / ' . $fbS; ?></td>
    <tr align="center">
        <td>Large / $3.55</td>
        <td width="200"><?php echo $c . number_format("$fbLQty",2,".",",") . ' / ' . $fbL; ?></td>
    <tr height="30" align="center" rowspan="2">
        <td width="200">Bacon Cheese Burger</td>
        <td width="200">Regular / $4.25</td>
        <td width="200"><?php echo $c . number_format("$bcQty",2,".",",") . ' / ' . $bcR; ?></td>
    <tr height="30" align="center" rowspan="2">
    <td width="200" rowspan="2">French Fries</td>
        <td width="200">Small / $0.99</td>
        <td width="200"><?php echo $c . number_format("$ffSQty",2,".",",") . ' / ' . $ffS; ?></td>
    <tr align="center">
        <td>Large / $1.99</td>
        <td width="200"><?php echo $c . number_format("$ffLQty",2,".",",") . ' / ' . $ffL; ?></td>
        <tr height="30" align="center" rowspan="2">
          <td colspan="3">Drinks</td>
        </tr>
    <tr height="30" align="center" rowspan="2">
        <td width="200">Cola</td>
        <td width="200">$2.75</td>
        <td width="200"><?php echo $c . number_format("$cola",2,".",",") . ' / ' . $colaQty; ?></td>
    <tr height="30" align="center" rowspan="2">
        <td widh="200">Juice</td>
        <td width="200">$3.55</td>
        <td width="200"><?php echo $c . number_format("$juice",2,".",",") . ' / ' . $juiceQty; ?></td>
    <tr height="100" align="center" rowspan="2">
        <td width="200">Beer</td>
        <td width="200">$4.25</td>
        <td width="200"><?php echo $c . number_format("$beer",2,".",",") . ' / ' . $beerQty; ?></td>
    <tr height="30" align="center" rowspan="2">
        <td width="200"></td>
        <td width="200"></td>
        <td width="200"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry... what? I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: @deceze from my html code you will see that I used the number_format for every variable or (calculated price). Those variables are different from each other, but is there any way that I can use a function that will make those variables in a `number_format` without declaring them within the table each time I needed it? I'm sorry but I'm so noob and appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$prices = array(
    'price1' => 0.70,
    'price2' => 1.75
);`

```
$price_formarted = array();
foreach($prices as $key => $val) {
    $price_formated[$key] = number_format($val);
}
```

Put the name you desire into 'price', loop througt a foreach, and add the number_format(); to each one.

Hope that is what you needed/asked

Comment: Thank you for your response. I can somehow get what you've provided. I made this changes

`$prices = array(
    'CBS' => 2.75,
    'CBL' => 3.55
);`


`$price_formarted = array();
foreach($prices as $key => $val) {
    $price_formated['CBS'] = number_format("$val",2,".",",");
}`

is this correct? Should I put this before or after the calculation of result? **Thank you!**

Comment: instead of putting 'CBS' inside the `foreach`, add `$key`, that will get the 'CBS', 'CBL' (that are the key from the array)... So then when you want to display the name, just put `echo $price_formated['CBS'];` to display the price.

Comment: thank you so much! it worked! Making it also easier to calculate the result within the array. Thank you thank you! :) `$prices = array(
    'CBS' => 2.75 * $cbS ,
    'CBL' => 3.55 * $cbL
);
$price_formated = array();
foreach($prices as $key => $val) {
    $price_formated[$key] = number_format("$val",2,".",",");
}`